# Creating a subdomain of a free subdomain

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain

I have a free subdomain and was wondering if I could create a subdomain of that subdomain.
e.g `foo.bar.example.com`

Comment: The place that you obtained that free subdomain might allow it, or they might prevent it.   What is that place?   Can you create your own DNS zone record for your subdomain?   Do they have a web interface for creating subdomains of your subdomains?

Comment: I am using batcave hosting

Comment: In theory, there is room for 4 levels from the TLD or domain name (I cannot remember which). But not all hosts are prepared for this. If you have your own machine, physical or virtual, and do not use a control panel to manage your system, then this should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the DNS of your domain this should be possible.

You can create a subdomain called `foo.bar.example.com` in your DNS, but of course it must point somewhere, e.g. `127.0.0.1`.

If you do not have DNS access this is most likely not possible. If your web host allows you to create subdomains, most likely you can add `subdomain.subdomain.domain`. If that's not possible and you do not have access to your DNS either, this isn't possible, unless your host has good support so they can add it to your DNS for you, that isn't hard at all.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just because a free host gives you a subdomain, they don't necessarily give you the control you need to create further subdomains from it.

When they create a subdomain for you, they add a DNS record to their domain name like:

```
yoursubdomain IN A 123.45.123.45
```

They also have the power to further subdivide it for you by adding records like:

```
www.yoursubdomain IN A 123.45.123.45
foo.yoursubdomain IN A 123.45.123.45
```

They would have to provide an interface for you to create these further subdomains.   You generally would not have the power to do this without support from your host.